# Add m3u8 file to audio unit in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, c

I want to add m3u8 file to audio unit .
I known how to play m3u8 in mp
movieplayer  ,avplayer. 
But In my case  i'm using audio unit , when i pass m3u8 file url it doesn't support.
It give error regarding type of url  . 
For more information . i wanna play m3u8 file from server to my app .. can any one suggest me how to deal with this problem.

Comment: is anyone knows above question